# What's the best way to allow an executable to run (with parameters) from any folder?

Tags: command-line

I currently downloaded a program, unziped it, and I can execute it by:

```
python3 demo.py 15263728
```

But the number may change and I would like to avoid moving to the extraction folder each time I need to use the command.

I guess it's not an alias because it's not something "fixed" but dynamic, since I'm passing an argument.

How can I do that? Or how can I google it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a short script, let's say `mydemo`:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/python3 /path/to/demo.py "$1"
```

(Change `/path/to/` to whatever is appropriate.) Make it executable, and place it either in `/usr/local/bin` or in a local directory that is in your $PATH.

From a command line, you can now enter

```
mydemo 15263728
```

independent of the current directory.

Comment: Good, but do not place in `/usr/bin` - this is managed by the APT system. Instead use `/usr/local/bin`; if for the user only, place in `~/.local/bin`, a directory that on Ubuntu is automatically included in the path if it exists

Comment: @vanadium Good point, edited.